# how to iterate data from django in angularJs

Tags: python, angularjs, django

This is my data from django models

```
subtaskList = [{'id':'1', 'name': 'sample name'},
{'id':'2', 'name': 'sample name 2'},
{'id':'3', 'name': 'sample name 3'}]
```

this is my code:

```
    var subtaskList = {{subtaskList}};


   var tasks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < subtaskList.length; i++ ) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) tasks.push([]);
        tasks[tasks.length-1].push(subtaskList[]);
    }
  return $scope.tasks = tasks;
```

If i use simple list like this it works:

```
subtaskList = ['wade', 'kobe','rose','rondo','butler', 'jordan'];
```

but if I use a dictionary list, It won't:

```
subtaskList = [{'id':'1', 'name': 'sample name'},
    {'id':'2', 'name': 'sample name 2'},
    {'id':'3', 'name': 'sample name 3'}]
```

please help me...

This is my html codes:

```
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="subtasks in tasks">
         <td ng-repeat="subtask in subtasks">
             {{ subtask.name }}
             <div ng-model=""></div>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: The best way is to render your dict into JSON as a seperate endpoint and load it with `$http.get()`.

Comment: How is data passed to Angular from Django?

Comment: var subtaskList = {{subtaskList}}. where {{}} is from django

Comment: It seems to me that there is a rather common misconception here: Django happens at server side. Angular happens at client side. You need a way to transport data.

Comment: Define "it wont", what *does* it do?

Comment: It won't show if I display it in html

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the Javascript portion of your code (assuming the following line is the actual code you have)

```
tasks[tasks.length-1].push(subtaskList[i])
```

this will create an array of array of objects for you. so if it is not working it is probably in the HTML template of your angularjs code. may be the ng-repeat has something in it that works with a string and not an object? would you mind sharing that part too?